# Problema con Webpack

Tags: webpack

```js
{
 "name": "webpack-curso",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "Curso de Webpack impartido por Fatzweb en Youtube",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack-dev-server -d --open",
  "start": "webpack -p"
 },
 "keywords": [
  "webpack",
  "webpack-development",
  "nodejs"
 ],
 "author": "Sergio Jurado Casado <juradonene@gmail.com>",
 "license": "MIT",
 "repository": "https://github.com/sergiojunene/webpack-fatz.git",
 "private": true,
 "devDependencies": {
  "autoprefixer": "^8.6.5",
  "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
  "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
  "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
  "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
  "image-webpack-loader": "^4.3.1",
  "marked": "^0.6.2",
  "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.1",
  "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
  "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
  "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
  "webpack": "^4.32.2",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.5.0"
 },
 "dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.16.4",
  "jquery": "^3.4.1"
 }
}
```

Tengo un problema con Webpack, antes no me había pasado nunca, y no sé por qué me está pasando esto.

Si me pueden ayudar, les agradezco.

Adjunto la imagen del error para que vean lo que pasa.

[image: Error en Consola]

```js
const browserSyncPlugin     = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const devMode        = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const CleanWebpackPlugin    = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin     = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin  = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const path          = require('path');
const marked         = require("marked");
const renderer        = new marked.Renderer();

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
 },
 watch: true,
 devtool: 'source-map',
 module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {loader: 'babel-loader' }
   },

      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
    use: [
     {
      loader: "style-loader",
      options: {sourceMap: true}
     },
     {
      loader: "css-loader",
      options: {sourceMap: true}
     },
     {
      loader: "sass-loader",
      options: {sourceMap: true}
     }
    ]
   },

   {
    test: /\.md$/,
    use: [
     {
      loader: "html-loader"
     },
     {
      loader: "markdown-loader",
      options: {
       pedantic: true,
       renderer
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new browserSyncPlugin({
      host:'localhost',
      files: ['./build/*.html'],
      port: 3000,
      server: { baseDir: ['build'] }
  }),

  new CleanWebpackPlugin({
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  }),

  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   title: 'My webpack App',
   description: 'Webpack is work',
   'meta': {
    'viewport': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no',
    'theme-color': '#4285f4'
   },
   template: './src/template.html',
   filename: 'index.html'
  }),

  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
   filename: devMode ? 'style.css' : 'style.[chunkhash].css',
  })
  ]

};
```

Además debe ser algún archivo de node_modules, otra vez he configurado así el código de Webpack y no me ha dado errores nunca, creen que es por la `const path()` ?

Me desespero cuando me salen errores absurdos que no sé arreglar, y luego seguro son tonterías, podría ser por sintaxis, pero dudo mucho que sea así.

Comment: Saludos bro, coloca el código copiando y pegando. Le harás la vida más fácil a quienes desean ayudarte :D

Comment: Mira que tu variable _this.paths sea de tipo array, ya que el metodo forEach esta solo para los arrays.

Comment: Código de mi archivo webpack:

Answer (score 0):

```
new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            path: path.resolve(__dirname + 'build')
        })
```

Era un problema de una coma y un + sign, tenía algunas líneas mal escritas, así que sobre todo en este plugin tuve que corregir algunas cosas que no estaban bien.